# Laravel Uploading .mp3 file not working | Post max size is 400 | All other format working

Tags: laravel

I am trying to upload .mp3 file in laravel 5.6 but it is not working. I checked with file size, file upload in php.ini and it is correct. All other format is supporting, even bigger file size. 
Please see the output of `dd(request('file'))` . .... My input filed name is file

Here is the output while uploading .m4a file

```
UploadedFile {#1171 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "670613 164.m4a"
  -mimeType: "audio/x-m4a"
  -size: 1740170
  -error: 0
  #hashName: null
  path: "/tmp"
  filename: "php5EChJc"
  basename: "php5EChJc"
  pathname: "/tmp/php5EChJc"
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/tmp/php5EChJc"
  aTime: 2020-05-29 11:28:05
  mTime: 2020-05-29 11:28:05
  cTime: 2020-05-29 11:28:05
  inode: 6557063
  size: 1740170
  perms: 0100600
  owner: 1000
  group: 1000
  type: "file"
  writable: true
  readable: true
  executable: false
  file: true
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

The output of .mp3 is given below.

```
UploadedFile {#1169 ▼
  -test: false
  -originalName: "aa.mp3"
  -mimeType: "application/octet-stream"
  -size: 0
  -error: 1
  #hashName: null
  path: ""
  filename: ""
  basename: ""
  pathname: ""
  extension: ""
  realPath: "/opt/lampp/htdocs/emsportsAdmin/public"
  aTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  mTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  cTime: 1970-01-01 00:00:00
  inode: false
  size: false
  perms: 00
  owner: false
  group: false
  type: false
  writable: false
  readable: false
  executable: false
  file: false
  dir: false
  link: false
}
```

I am running laravel in xampp ubuntu

Comment: Is it your validation problem or others???

Comment: Its not validation problem. I am not validating the content